# Как запускать действие каждый раз когда SwitchCompat Button включена?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-switch

Есть кнопка-переключатель SwitchCompat, когда она включена должно прийти локальное уведомление. Проблема в том, что если установить время, потом включить тумблер то уведомление придет, но если оставить тумблер включенным и задать новое время на уведомление, то оно не придет пока не выключить и снова включить тумблер. Как это исправить? Я так понимаю программа только один раз проверяет включен ли тумблер или нет?

Участок кода Activity:

```
public class AlarmActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    private EditText mondayText;
    private SwitchCompat mondaySwitch;
    SharedPreferences sPref;
    String timeText = "";
    final String SAVED_TEXT = "saved_text";
    boolean switch_On_Off;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Switch_On_Off_check";
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);

        mondayText = findViewById(R.id.monday_time);
        mondaySwitch = findViewById(R.id.switch_monday);

        // load SharedPref save text in mondayText and save switch On else Off
        loadText();
        loadSwitchCheck();

        mondaySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                startAlarm(c);
                saveSwitchCheck();

            }
        });


        mondayText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
                timePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "time picker");
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        updateTimeText(c);
    }

    private void updateTimeText(Calendar c) {

        // clean EditText time
        timeText = "";
        timeText += DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(c.getTime());
        mondayText.setText(timeText);
        saveText();

    }

    public void startAlarm(Calendar c) {

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, 0);

        if (c.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    }
```

Значит, сделал проверку на включение/выключение переключателя (или я так думаю, что сделал) но теперь уведомление приходит всегда, полностью игнорируется переменная boolean OnOff

Исправленный код:

```
public class AlarmActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    private EditText mondayText;
    public SwitchCompat mondaySwitch;
    SharedPreferences sPref;
    String timeText = "";
    final String SAVED_TEXT = "saved_text";
    boolean switch_On_Off;
    boolean OnOff;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Switch_On_Off_check";
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);

        mondayText = findViewById(R.id.monday_time);
        mondaySwitch = findViewById(R.id.switch_monday);

        // load SharedPref save text in mondayText and save switch On else Off
        loadText();
        loadSwitchCheck();

        mondaySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if (mondaySwitch.isChecked()) {

                    OnOff = true;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Включено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    OnOff = false;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Выключено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                saveSwitchCheck();

            }
        });

        mondayText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
                timePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "time picker");
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        updateTimeText(c);

        if (OnOff = true) {
            startAlarm(c);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Включите", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void updateTimeText(Calendar c) {

        timeText = "";
        timeText += DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(c.getTime());
        mondayText.setText(timeText);
        saveText();

    }

    public void startAlarm(Calendar c) {


        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, 0);

        if (c.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

    }
```

Comment: у вас будильник запускается в методе `startAlarm()` который запускается при смене состояния `SwitchCompat`  именно поэтому только если выключить/включить приходит уведомление.

Comment: Если вы хотите чтобы `SwitchCompat` было неким подтверждением чтобы работал будильник то запускайте `startAlarm()` в методе `onTimeSet()`, а к `SwitchCompat` привяжите  какую нибудь `boolean` переменную которая отражает состояние `SwitchCompat` и проверяйте в `onTimeSet()` по ней включен ли `SwitchCompat`. Можете конечно другое решение найти

Comment: @sakuraso13 я думал, написать условие, при котором когда задаётся новое время, switch button выключалась потом включалась, но не понравилось тем, что слишком топорно мне кажется. Попробуй ваш предложенный способ

Comment: уважаемый @sakuraso13 значит сделал изменения, но теперь почему-то уведомления приходят всегда. исправленный код добавил в вопрос. Буду благодарен любой помощи

Comment: А методы `saveSwitchCheck();` `loadSwitchCheck();`  посмотрите может в них дело

Comment: @sakuraso13 это сохранение состояние в sharedPreference. Простое состояние должно сохранять и при запуске приложения запускать

Comment: @sakuraso13 попробуй тоже перенести в метод OnTimeSet

Comment: @sakuraso13 отключил эти методы, дело не в них.....

Comment: @Barmaley может Вы дадите подсказку....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На данный момент нашел только одно решение, выключать через код switch переключатель каждый раз, когда пользователь устанавливает новое время, так как данное напоминание будет работать раз в неделю в указанное время, пользователь не будет часто менять время уведомления, если будет нужда, всегда можно написать строчку, чтобы при установки нового времени переключатель сначала выключался, а потом снова включался. Если кому понадобится, код прилагаю:

```
public class AlarmActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {


    private EditText mondayText;
    public SwitchCompat mondaySwitch;
    SharedPreferences sPref;
    String timeText = "";
    final String SAVED_TEXT = "saved_text";
    boolean switch_On_Off;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Switch_On_Off_check";
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);
        mondayText = findViewById(R.id.monday_time);
        mondaySwitch = findViewById(R.id.switch_monday);
        // load SharedPref save text in mondayText and save switch On else Off
        loadText();
        loadSwitchCheck();

        mondaySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (mondaySwitch.isChecked()) {
                    // запуск уведомления если активирован переключатель
                    startAlarm(c);

                }
                saveSwitchCheck();
            }
        });

        mondayText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment timePicker = new TimePickerFragment();
                timePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "time picker");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
         // деактивируем переключатель
         mondaySwitch.setChecked(false);
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
       // после установки времени активируем переключатель без участия пользователя (при желании) 
         mondaySwitch.setChecked(true);
        updateTimeText(c);


        saveText();
    }

    private void updateTimeText(Calendar c) {
        // clear old time text
        timeText = "";
        timeText += DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(c.getTime());
        mondayText.setText(timeText);
    }

    public void startAlarm(Calendar c) {

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlertReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, 0);
        if (c.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
    }
```